# c# ComboBox isSelected doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

so I'm trying to change the value IsSelected on ComboBox item in code:

```
if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("tempValue"))
     {
         switch (roamingSettings.Values["tempValue"].ToString())
             {
                  case "Celsius":
                      Celsius.IsSelected = true;
                      break;
                  case "Kelvin":
                      Kelvin.IsSelected = true;
                      break;
                  case "Fahrenheit":
                      Fahrenheit.IsSelected = true;
                      break;
              }
    }
```

This code gets triggered on page restore, logic works fine, the value gets passed onto "OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)" method (I've borrowed this method from Microsoft UWP Examples) and I can see that e.Content has the correct value. But the item doesn't get selected. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

ps. Complete code on https://github.com/4c74356b41/UWP-04 (this happens on settings.xaml and settings.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you don't force an item to be seleted, but force the combobox to select an item ?

Something like

```
switch (roamingSettings.Values["tempValue"].ToString())
         {
              case "Celsius":
                  ComboBox.selectedItem = Celsius;
                  break;
              case "Kelvin":
                  ComboBox.selectedItem = Kelvin;
                  break;
              case "Fahrenheit":
                  ComboBox.selectedItem = Fahrenheit;
                  break;
          }
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Exactly as it was designed to be used.

Comment: Thanks @JerryNixon-MSFT